SQL query nested arrays JSON Snowflake
I am trying to query a table in Snowflake that is built with a single field labeled "Value" and each row is a separate JSON object.
Row 1: {
  "artist": {
    "artistID": "artist_1",
    "artistName": "Roblox"
  },
  "descriptors": {
    "styles": [
      {
        "ID": "84121",
        "weight": "63"
      },
      {
        "ID": "83983",
        "weight": "14"
      }
    ],
  "duration": "240509",
   "productCodes": [
    {
      "type": "ISRC",
      "value": "isrc_1"
    }
  ]
}

Row 2: {
  "artist": {
    "artistID": "artist_2",
    "artistName": "Minecraft"
  },
  "descriptors": {
    "styles": [
      {
        "ID": "84122",
        "weight": "12"
      },
      {
        "ID": "83983",
        "weight": "14"
      }
    ],
  "duration": "400001",
   "productCodes": [
    {
      "type": "ISRC",
      "value": "isrc_2"
    }
  ]
}

Row 3: {
  "artist": {
    "artistID": "artist_3",
    "artistName": "Fortnite"
  },
  "descriptors": {
    "styles": [
      {
        "ID": "84121",
        "weight": "47"
      },
      {
        "ID": "83983",
        "weight": "14"
      }
    ],
  "duration": "300001",
  "productCodes": [
    {
      "type": "ISRC",
      "value": "isrc_3"
    },
    {
      "type": "ISRC",
      "value": "isrc_4"
    }
  ]
}

What I am trying to do is SELECT a column which includes all of the ISRCs, and another column which includes their associated styles. As you can see, some rows can have multiple ISRCs, and each row can have multiple styles. The output dataframe should look like this:

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the nested arrays - can you point me in the right direction? Thank you!

this worked for me :
WITH json_data AS (
  SELECT 
    PARSE_JSON('{
      "artist": {
        "artistID": "artist_1",
        "artistName": "Roblox"
      },
      "descriptors": {
        "styles": [
          {
            "ID": "84121",
            "weight": "63"
          },
          {
            "ID": "83983",
            "weight": "14"
          }
        ],
        "duration": "240509",
        "productCodes": [
          {
            "type": "ISRC",
            "value": "isrc_1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }') AS data
)

SELECT 
  pc.value:value::string AS isrc,
  s.value:ID::string AS style_id,
  s.value:weight::string AS style_weight
FROM json_data jd,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => jd.data:descriptors:productCodes) pc,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => jd.data:descriptors:styles) s
WHERE pc.value:type::string = 'ISRC';

Output


Appreciate this! Your query is working for me on the sample data. However, I'm getting null results when querying the actual table, like so:
WITH json_data AS (
SELECT
PARSE_JSON(value) AS data
FROM source_table
)
SELECT
pc.value:value::string AS isrc,
s.value:ID::string AS style_id,
s.value:weight::string AS style_weight
FROM json_data jd,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => jd.data:descriptors:productCodes) pc,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => jd.data:descriptors:styles) s
WHERE pc.value:type::string = 'ISRC'
;
Any idea why this would fail?

your json column is in string or object format ?

the column type is listed as VARIANT in snowflake. is there a way I can check if it's string or object?

VARIANT is a flex type so it can contains all type (array, object, ..), try to remove the parse_json

noted that my sample data was structured incorrectly - product codes were not nested under descriptors in the true data set. Have fixed this on my end and it works correctly. Thanks!

So using a CTE just like Ahmed:
with cte_data(value) as (
    select parse_json($1) from values
    ('{"artist":{"artistID":"artist_1","artistName":"Roblox"},"descriptors":{"duration":"240509","productCodes":[{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_1"}],"styles":[{"ID":"84121","weight":"63"},{"ID":"83983","weight":"14"}]}}'),
    ('{"artist":{"artistID":"artist_2","artistName":"Minecraft"},"descriptors":{"duration":"400001","productCodes":[{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_2"}],"styles":[{"ID":"84122","weight":"12"},{"ID":"83983","weight":"14"}]}}'),
    ('{"artist":{"artistID":"artist_3","artistName":"Fortnite"},"descriptors":{"duration":"300001","productCodes":[{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_3"},{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_4"}],"styles":[{"ID":"84121","weight":"47"},{"ID":"83983","weight":"14"}]}}')
)
select * from cte_data

this really could be a table, but a CTE makes no clean-up.
so that is your example data, and you are JOIN to projections from that data together with an implicit CROSS JOIN that is what the comma after the FROM table name does.
I explain this, because you mention, your code get you null:
because if I use the SQL you put into the comment against, CTE of your data it works:
with cte_data(data) as (
    select parse_json($1) from values
    ('{"artist":{"artistID":"artist_1","artistName":"Roblox"},"descriptors":{"duration":"240509","productCodes":[{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_1"}],"styles":[{"ID":"84121","weight":"63"},{"ID":"83983","weight":"14"}]}}'),
    ('{"artist":{"artistID":"artist_2","artistName":"Minecraft"},"descriptors":{"duration":"400001","productCodes":[{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_2"}],"styles":[{"ID":"84122","weight":"12"},{"ID":"83983","weight":"14"}]}}'),
    ('{"artist":{"artistID":"artist_3","artistName":"Fortnite"},"descriptors":{"duration":"300001","productCodes":[{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_3"},{"type":"ISRC","value":"isrc_4"}],"styles":[{"ID":"84121","weight":"47"},{"ID":"83983","weight":"14"}]}}')
)
SELECT 
    pc.value:value::string AS isrc, 
    s.value:ID::string AS style_id, 
    s.value:weight::string AS style_weight 
FROM cte_data as jd, 
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => jd.data:descriptors:productCodes) as pc, 
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => jd.data:descriptors:styles) as s 
WHERE pc.value:type::string = 'ISRC' ; 




ISRC
STYLE_ID
STYLE_WEIGHT




isrc_1
84121
63


isrc_1
83983
14


isrc_2
84122
12


isrc_2
83983
14


isrc_3
84121
47


isrc_3
83983
14


isrc_4
84121
47


isrc_4
83983
14



so to debug this I would first check pc is flatten'ing correctly:
SELECT 
    pc.value:value::string AS isrc
FROM cte_data as jd, 
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => jd.data:descriptors:productCodes) as pc


if you get for your example data, 4+ row of null, you are pulling pc.value apart incorreclty.
if you get zero rows, the data you are feeding into the flatten is wrong.
if you get four perfect rows as my picture, you can now swap to check the values getting pulled apart for s.
another thing you can do to check what way the data is, is to cast jd.data to text and the push into parse_json and see if it then works.
SELECT 
    pc.value:value::string AS isrc
FROM cte_data as jd, 
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => parse_json(jd.data::text):descriptors:productCodes) as pc


To achieve this, you’ll need to parse out the nested JSON structure and use LATERAL FLATTEN in Snowflake, which helps handle arrays within JSON fields. Here’s a query that should provide the output you need by flattening both the productCodes and styles arrays:
SELECT 
value:artist:artistName::string AS artistName,
productCode.value AS ISRC,
style.value:ID::string AS styleID,
style.value:weight::string AS styleWeight FROM your_table_name,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => value:productCodes) AS productCode,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => value:descriptors:styles) AS style WHERE 
productCode.value:type::string = 'ISRC';

Explanation:

Flatten the productCodes array: LATERAL FLATTEN(input => value:productCodes) extracts each product code entry from the productCodes array.
Filter for ISRC type: Using WHERE productCode.value:type::string = 'ISRC' ensures only rows with the ISRC type are included.
Flatten the styles array: Similarly, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => value:descriptors:styles) retrieves each style from the styles array.
Select required columns: Retrieve the artistName, ISRC from productCodes, and styleID and styleWeight from the styles array.

This should give you a result where each row shows an artistName, an ISRC, and associated styleID and styleWeight, with one row per combination of ISRC and style. Adjust column casting if needed based on your exact JSON structure.
